# Node.js Express REST API - accessing JSON url params with GET request

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, get

I have a REST endpoint that is /geo/search and requires a number of long/lat coordinates to be sent as part of the request (GEO polygon).

- Is there any way I can use JSON in the GET request? I was thinking that that URL encoding may be a solution:

  ```
  var data = encodeURIComponent({"coordinates":[[-122.610168,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.598167]]});
  ```
- How would I access these params in the route?

Comment: For your first question, have a look at [JQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Comment: And for your second question, if you use `JQuery.param`, then you can just access the coordinates using `req.query.coordinates[x][y]` in the route in Express.

Comment: Why not use the query string?  That's what it's there for.  You can either use the PHP/Rails/jQuery-style query string parameters with arrays as already mentioned, or you could just encode everything as JSON, encode it properly for the query string, and assign to a variable like `data` or something.  There are lots of ways to handle this, but the last thing I would do in this case is attach it to part of the path.

Comment: No - see my second comment. You should be using `req.query` not `req.params`.

Comment: Thanks @mccannf but req.query.coordinates returns undefined.

Comment: @Brad - thanks for the comment. "but the last thing I would do in this case is attach it to part of the path" - clearly im missing something obvious, but what option do I have with a GET request? I know theres debates on sending a body with a GET, but can you clarify?

Comment: @Ben I'm saying that you should put these things in the query string instead of part of the path.  `/example/path?queryStringVar1=value1&queryStingVar2=value2`  Why try to match on just a big blob of data for your path while recreating the entire purpose of the query string's existence?

Comment: @Brad - ahh I see! Yes, confusion with the path vs parameters. Thanks very much for the clarification - very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to #1 - thanks to @mccannf

Using JQuery.param:

Client:

```
var test = {"coordinates":[[-122.610168,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.598167]]};

    console.log($.param( test ));
```

Outputs:

```
coordinates%5B0%5D%5B%5D=-122.610168&coordinates%5B0%5D%5B%5D=37.598167&coordinates%5B1%5D%5B%5D=-122.288818&coordinates%5B1%5D%5B%5D=37.598167&coordinates%5B2%5D%5B%5D=-122.288818&coordinates%5B2%5D%5B%5D=37.845833&coordinates%5B3%5D%5B%5D=-122.610168&coordinates%5B3%5D%5B%5D=37.845833&coordinates%5B4%5D%5B%5D=-122.610168&coordinates%5B4%5D%5B%5D=37.598167
```

Answer to #2 - thanks to @Brad:

Server - Express route:

```
router.get('/search_polygon', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Server received: ' + JSON.stringify(req.query.coordinates));
...
```

Outputs:

```
Server received: [["-122.610168","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.598167"]]
```

My issue was trying to pass these as part of the path, and not as parameters as they should be.